# Regex to find period in square brackets

Tags: sql, regex, vba

I am parsing some SQL statements and have found places where the SELECT statement may be:

`SELECT [tblCustomer].[FirstName], [tblCustomer.LastName], [tblOrder].[Order_No]`

and as you see the second column has a `.` inside the square brackets.  This is acceptable in Access SQL but not SQL Server.  I'm trying to build a RegEx to identify when there is a `.` inside square brackets and replace it with `].[`

I've tried:  `\[.+?\](?![\.])` which will get me a period inside square brackets but it doesn't stop searching when it finds the closing bracket.

I'm using ECMAScript to be compatible with VBA and I don't have concerns about nested brackets.

Example:  https://regex101.com/r/Inxhdg/1/

Comment: could you just replace the `].[` with `.` then replace the `.` with `].[`?

Comment: `replace(replace("SELECT [tblCustomer].[FirstName], [tblCustomer.LastName], [tblOrder].[Order_No]","].[","."),".","].[")`

Comment: @ScottCraner I like the way you're thinking but this will also find legitimate `.`'s and replace them with `].['.   Example:  `replace(replace("SELECT [tblCustomer].[FirstName], [tblCustomer.LastName], tblOrder.Order_No","].[","."),".","].[")`

Comment: correct it assumed that all were `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

*Search for*: `(\[\w+)\.(?=\w+])`
*Replace with*: `$1].[`

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/akxrXw/1). **Details**:

- `(\[\w+)` - Group 1 (`$1`): `[` and then any one or more letters, digits, or underscores
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?=\w+])` - a positive lookahead that requires one or more letters, digits or underscores and then a `]` char immediately to the right of the current location.